# Instagram and oAuth

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm writing an application that will integrate with Instagram. In order for me to access some of the API, Instagram requires me to authenticate with oAuth. I've *never* used oAutho before and am completely lost. Specifically, I'm going to be doing this in Python (not my strong language) and, thus, don't know where to start.

So I know that, before anything, I need to get an oAuth token. The Instagram site gave me a client_secret and a client_id. But it it also gave me a redirect URI. I know these three things are supposed to be used together but I don't know how.

Since this is a desktop app, will I be required to use some sort of web component?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want a module like https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram,

An example from the site

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

api = InstagramAPI(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID', client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
for media in popular_media:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

Comment: Thank you! I came across a reference to python-instagram but the GitHub link failed and I couldn't find it on the site. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to recommend that you play around with a pre-existing piece of code to help you understand how a lot of python works with Instagram. Try using

https://github.com/oh-moore/followpie

or

https://github.com/marclave/InstaBot

Using either of these will help you figure out how your oAuth works, and they already come with error messaging, debugging, etc. You can just fill in the blanks and start hacking from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some decent oAuth python libraries that make this pretty easy. The one recommended on the oAuth site is [`python-oauth2`](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2).

There are examples there using Django and the twitter API - this should be pretty easy to adapt for Instagram.